# Hexproof vs enchantment affecting all creatures

Tags: magic-the-gathering

My opponent controls [Plated Crusher](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Plated%20Crusher), a 7/6 hexproof creature. I control two [Dampening Pulse](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Dampening%20Pulse)s, which give opponents' creatures -1/-0. Would Dampening Pulse affect the hexproof creature? I think it would because it's not directly targeting the hexproof creature.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, Dampening Pulse will affect creatures your opponents control that have Hexproof. The entire relevant part of the definition of Hexproof ([rule 702.11b](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Hexproof)) is

> “Hexproof” on a permanent means “This permanent can’t be the target of spells or abilities your opponents control.”

Then, [rule 114.9a](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Targets) says

> Just because an object or player is being affected by a spell or ability doesn’t make that object or player a target of that spell or ability. **Unless that object or player is identified by the word “target” in the text of that spell or ability, or the rule for that keyword ability, it’s not a target.**

Dampening Pulse doesn't use the word "target" and it doesn't have any keyword abilities (targeted or otherwise), so Hexproof doesn't affect it.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct--hexproof only prevents spells and abilities which use the "target" keyword. Dampening Pulse does not specify a target, so it will still affect your opponent's creature.